# Why does my python code run perfectly fine on runestone but not on vscode?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

```
def CreditPay(rate, payment, verbose):
    balance = 1000 # Amount currently owed
    month = 1  #Number of months
    paid = 0    # Amount paid so far

    while balance > payment:
        balance = balance + balance*rate/100 - payment
        paid += payment
        if verbose:
            print(f'Balance after month {month} is $ {balance}.')

        month += 1
    print(f"Final payment is $ {balance}")
    print(f'Final amount paid is $ {balance+paid}')
        
    return month

nmonths = CreditPay(2.5,100,False)
print("Number of months to pay off is", nmonths)

nmonths = CreditPay(2.5,100,True)
print("Number of months to pay off is", nmonths)

                                                   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
martin@Martins-Air ~ % python -u "/Users/martin/Downloads/assignment7"
File "/Users/martin/Downloads/assignment7", line 19
print(f'Balance after month {month} is $ {balance}.')
^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please do not post code as images.  Instead, copy/paste your code into your question, properly formatting it via the `{}` tool on the editor's toolbar.  Also post results and error messages as text whenever possible.

Comment: My guess is that you are using an older version of Python when running in VSCode, one that does not support f-strings.  This feature was added in Python 3.6.  Check to see if you're running with an earlier version of Python than that when you get the error.  If so, upgrading your Python version will fix the problem.  To test this hypothesis without changing Python versions, change the code to not use the f-string feature and see if it then runs ok.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - of course.  fat finger move :)

Comment: @CryptoFool thank you, its def the f-string thats not working. I just changed my interpreter to python 3.8.2 but its still continuing to not work. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What python interpreter are you using? f-string got introduced in python3.
To select your python interpreter with Vscode open up the command line windows  ctrl+shift+p or macos cmd+shift+p and then search for "python interpreter".
the complete command should look like this

```
>Python: Select Interpreter and then simply click on any Python 3.x.x
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, its definitely the f-string but even when i changed my interpreter to 3.8.2 it still wont run it. I restarted vscode multiple times and made sure to check the version before running my code.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I downloaded code runner extension. I had to go to its *settings.json* and change `python -u` to `python3 -u`. thanks for the help. still new to programming.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).